# Unable to search for Mails based on subject

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am trying to search for mails in Outlook based on the list mentioned in a column in the Excel sheet. Below is the code in VBA which I have written. But its not working. Please help:

```
    Sub Test()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Namespace
Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
Dim olMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim n As Variant


Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder("Test1" as OlDefaultFolders)
'Set rng = [D3:D10]
n = Cells(4, 4).Value
'For Each n In rng
'i = Int(n)

'Cells(i, 10).Text = Cells(i, 4).Text
For Each olMail In Fldr.Items
If InStr(olMail.Subject, "n") <> 0 Then
Cells(3, 4).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Y"
Else
Cells(3, 4).Offset(0, 1).Value = "N"
End If


Next olMail

'Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: `If InStr(olMail.Subject, "n") <> 0 Then` try without the `""` around n?

Comment: @findwindow Tried that...   Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder("Test1" as OlDefaultFolders) is giving error

Comment: I am not too familiar with outlook methods XD I presume you have `test1` as a folder?

Comment: Drop the `as OlDefaultFolders` so it's just `Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder("Test1")` assuming you have such folder. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866724.aspx)

Comment: @findwindow ....Thanks for your responses... Tried this as well but its not working... now its saying 'Type mismatch'

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use GetDefaultFolder for anything but, well - the default folders (Inbox, Contacts, Calendar, etc.).  To get a specific folder you need know the folder's EntryID and use NameSpace.GetFolderFromID or "walk" through Folders collections from a specific root Folder object (e.g. myInboxFolderObject.Folders("MyInboxSubFolder").

Also see "[Enumerating, Searching, and Filtering Items in a Folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff869362.aspx)".

Comment: Hi Eric Legault, sorry for the delayed response. Could you please elaborate as to how I can implement in this program.... Thanks,

Comment: Can you be more specific? Did you review the article in the link I provided?  Which mechanism makes sense for your solution? Do you have any questions about any of the specific approaches?

Comment: Hi Eric, I am not well versed in this. But still wanted to work on this. However, when I visited the link you gave, i felt confusing. Hence requesting you to help on this.

Comment: Is the problem mainly trying to get a reference to the items in the "Test1" folder?  If so, you can't use GetDefaultFolder - that only works with the default folders.  If "Test1" is under the Inbox, then go ahead and use GetDefaultFolder to get the Inbox folder as a myInboxFolder variable (Folder object), then call Set myTestFolder = myInboxFolder.Folders("Test").  If the "Test1" folder is under a folder at the root, then get the root folder from myInboxFolder.Parent, then "walk" the Folders collection until you get the folder you need.  Does this help?